# changing a float inside a nested list

Tags: python, list, floating-point, nested-lists

I'm new to python and I have a small challenge I am facing right now
I have this list `nested_list = [['1','2','3'],['2','4','6']]`
I would like to change the strings of the list to their float representation
while keeping the order the same it is

```
new_list = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],[2.0,4.0,6.0]]
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `float` for each item in each nested list:

```
new_list = [[float(x) for x in lst] for lst in nested_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done using `map` on the nested lists:

```
new_list = [list(map(float, lst)) for lst in nested_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like as below if you've installed `numpy` module. In this code `for-loop` doesn't exist. You don't want to install `numpy` module just for this though...

```
import numpy as np
nested_list = [['1','2','3'],['2','4','6']]
new_lst = np.array(nested_list, dtype=np.float).tolist()
```

Answer (score -1):

Using two loops are not good option for this little task ,  importing any external module is also not good option:

> One line solution without any loop:

```
nested_list = [['1','2','3'],['2','4','6']]

print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:float(y),x)),nested_list)))
```

> output:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]]
```

Comment: `map(lambda y:float(y),x)` is unnecessarily complicated, it is equivalent to `map(float, x)`

Comment: Also, I think it is incorrect to say your code does not use two loops, because when you call `list()` on a `map`object, it necessarily loops over the `map`'s iterable to construct the new list. Unless of course I've misunderstood what `list(map(...))` is doing...